# AWS forward port 8000 from elb to port 8000 of EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, portforwarding, elastic-load-balancer

I have en ELB with multiple EC2 instances registered in target groups. I am using port a php application which is running properly. It has SSL.

I want to use port 8000 for my node application. What I would like to do is I want to forward my-elb-address:8000 to any-ec2-ip:8000. So when i access the domain attached to ELB witjh port 8000 it would forward that to ec2 with port 8000. How can I accomplish this? Is their any other way of ELB listening and forwarding multiple ports?

I have added listener for port 80,443 and 8000 in my ELB. Please help

Answer (score 3):

### Classic ELB

Using the "classic" ELB you can define custom rules for forwarding the ports in the AWS dashboard:

[image]

Mind that the requests will be forwarded to **all** the available instances, which means in the example above (supposing *php* is running on the 80, *node.js* on the 8000) all the instances must have both the services running. If the services are instead on different instances you will need two different load balancers, one per port.

### Application ELB

Another option is to use an "application" ELB (ALB). 
This option will allow to have single load balancer with fine-grained rules that will allow, for each protocol, to forward the request to a set of instances.

- create a "default" ALB
- add a new *target group* (see entry under the *Load Balancing* section in the sidebar) listening on your custom port
- register the instances running your *node.js* application (right click on the target group)
- bind the target group to the listeners of your ALB

Another solution could be, specifying path-based rules, to use only one port (443) and forward only the requests under `/to_nodejs` to the port 8000.

Comment: To be honest I have been trying to find it under my load balancer's listen tab, I cant find this UI there. Can you please help me where can I find it?

Comment: Okay Thanks I got it, its in the ELB setup wizard :|

Comment: You can also edit an existing caller from the listener tab

Comment: Actually I have an application load balancer, which doesnt have such options. I had to create a classic load balancer for this. :\

Comment: An ALB doesn't let you specify a custom port to forward to, only listen. Everything still gets forward under port 80 or 443.